# Push notification on shutdown

Tags: scripts, shutdown, notification

I want to push notification on shutting down ubuntu
i.e, when I do a normal shutdown, shutdown gets delayed for 5sec and in that time interval I get my notification

Is it possible to do?

Comment: A push notification to ... your phone? If so, "Yes, with caveats". Why would the shutdown need to get delayed for 5 seconds, though?

Comment: no, to ubuntu...5secods so that user can see that notification...I guess I should change to "how to delay normal shutdown action by 5 sec"...is that possible

Comment: One option would be to use [notify-send](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/en/man1/notify-send.1.html), if the person is using Gnome. However, this notification would not appear if the person is in DND mode. ⇢ Try it out with `notify-send "Shutdown Sequence Initiated" "We're about to shut down the computer."`